# How to debug Node TypeScript in Visual Studio Code when the JavaScript source is in a different folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

From Visual Studio Code, I am able to debug and step through the TypeScript source of Main.ts,  provided the JavaScript and map files coexist in the **same** folder as the TypeScript source.

This arrangement works -

```
debugDemo\
     .vscode
              launch.json        
     TypeScript\
               Main.ts
               Main.js
               Main.js.map
```

However, I don't want the JavaScript files in the TypeScript folder, but instead would like the JavaScript in the
JavaScript folder. I understand this can be achieved via a launch.json configuration using the
outFiles attribute to identify where to locate the JavaScript.

For me, this arrangement does not work -

```
debugDemo\
     .vscode
              launch.json        
     TypeScript\
               Main.ts
    JavaScript\        
               Main.js
               Main.js.map
```

The error is always  -
**"Cannot launch program 'c:\debugDemo\TypeScript\Main.ts'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help"**

[image]
What is wrong, how can I configure Visual Studio Code to look for the JavaScript files in the JavaScript folder? I experimented with various glob patterns for **outFiles**, but it did not help  resolve the issue.

**Main.ts**
Reduced to one line of code to reduce the problem complexity

```
  console.log("debug");
```

Mapfiles built via

```
tsc --sourcemap TypeScript/Main.ts
```

which generates -  TypeScript\Main.js , TypeScript\Main.js.map

**launch.json**

```
   {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Test",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/TypeScript/Main.ts",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/JavaScript/**/*.js"],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

- TypeScript version:  2.1.4
- Node version: 6.9.4
- Visual Studio  Code  version: 1.14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `tsc --sourcemap TypeScript/Main.ts` does not output the files into `JavaScript` folder. You have to specify the [`outDir`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and specify the `JavaScript` folder:

```
tsc --sourcemap --outDir "JavaScript"  TypeScript/Main.ts
```

See [TypeScript compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Thanks.   I  manually copied the JavaScript files. That was my mistake.  
The  generated map files are now of  the form "sources":["../TypeScript/Main.ts"]